# VSTS naming convention and allowed characters for Tags

Tags: azure-devops, naming-conventions

**Background**

I'm a new VSTS administrator who has successfully completed the initial configuration of a new VSTS account. As part of Phase 1 of our VSTS implementation, I've only configured the project management aspects of VSTS (e.g. things related to entering, maintaining, and reviewing work items such as area paths, iterations, product backlog items, tasks, etc.). Other technical aspects of VSTS (source code repositories, test case management, automated builds and releases, etc.) have not been implemented yet.

I temporarily postponed the configuration of *Tags* in VSTS. I have several other systems which follow a unified tagging schema. I'd like our VSTS tags to conform to the existing tags we implemented for our other systems (to the greatest extent possible). I realize that I might not be able to achieve full conformity, but that is the ideal goal.

**Question**

What is the naming convention for Tags in VSTS?

In other words, I'd like to know what rules govern the creation of tags in VSTS. For example, I'd like to know what characters are allowed or disallowed, maximum character length, etc.

I was not able to find this information with respect to Tags in Microsoft's online documentation. I did find this article which describes various VSTS naming conventions:

[Naming restrictions and conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/organizations/settings/naming-restrictions?view=vsts)

Unfortunately, that detailed article seems to have completely omitted rules for defining Tags.

Comment: Apart from `,` and `;` there are pretty much no limiations.

Comment: Seems not official article mentions it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've confirmed the response received from **jessehouwing** with respect to commas and semicolons being disallowed. I also tested a few other specific cases relevant to my requirements, and here's what I found that works ok:

- white spaces
- numbers
- letters
- special characters including but not limited to ! < > . ? ~

If I discover any additional disallowed special characters (besides the ones mentioned by jessehouwing) or if I find an authoritative document published by Microsoft, I'll update this post.